# A polynomial algorithm to determine whether a finite group is nilpotent

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, computational-complexity, nilpotent-groups

Does there exist a polynomial (in respect to the order of the group) algorithm that given a Cayley table of a finite group determines, whether a group is nilpotent or not?

There do exist polynomial algorithms, that determine, whether a group is *nilpotent of degree k* or not. The simplest of them is simply checking the necessary commutator identity for all $(k + 1)$-ples of elements of the group (this algorithm works for $O(n^{k + 1})$, where $n$ is the order of the group). However, none of them can be used to determine in polynomial time, whether a group is *nilpotent of arbitrary degree*.

Comment: Back in the day when the usenet group sci.math was still functional we had a very efficient algorithm for tasks like this - wait for Derek Holt to show up! The running time was more or less a constant.

Comment: In practice  groups are not defined by Cayley tables, so this is not the right question. If the group is given by generators as a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$, then nilpotency and solvability can be decided in time polynomial in $n$. It's more interesting for subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$, in which case I think nilpotency and solvability can be decided in polynomial time by methods involving randomiztrion, so they have a small probability of running for a very long time.

Comment: @DerekHolt how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple (but inefficient) way to test nilpotency in polynomial time would be to compute its lower central series and see whether the final group is trivial or not.

Each commutator subgroup computation takes $O(n^2)$ time, and since the orders of the groups in this central series do not increase, they must stabilise in at most $O(\log n)$ steps (by way of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic – the worst case is when the orders halve at each step). Thus, this algorithm takes $O(n^2\log n)$ time.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the first step. Sure, there are $\binom n 2$ commutators in a group of order $n$ (many of them trivial), but are you implying that we can determine the subgroup they generate in $O(n^2)$ time, too? I don't have anything like a counterexample in mind, but this is not obvious to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The first phase is to determine all the commutators, which obviously takes $O(n^2)$ time. Then a hash table of the known elements in the commutator subgroup can be maintained, as well as the set of combinations of commutators tried. When the first hash table stops growing, closure has been reached; at most $O(n^2)$ commutator combinations need be tried for this second phase.

Comment: Thanks. That will do.